# How to retrieve a clicked element in a Jquery treeview

Tags: jquery, treeview

I am willing to use the jquery treeview.  I have categories and subcategories to choose for an item and I would like to display them in a treeview. I would like then to get the clicked value.

for the moment I am working on something of the kind of  :

```
<ul id="treeview">
    <li>group1a
        <ul>
            <li>group11 </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>group2 </li>
    <li>group3 </li>
    <li>group4 </li>
    <li>group5 </li>
</ul>
```

and I tried this script, but the click function throw me an error.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $().ready(function () {
                $("#treeview").treeview();
            });

            $("#treeview").click(function (e) {
                e.target.addClass("selected");
            });

</script>
```

I am a very big beginner to this Jquery way of handling things, so I assume I am missing some important point somewhere... thanks for your help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `addClass` is an jQuery method, while `e.target` is not a jQuery object. You need to enclose it in `$()`:

```
$("#treeview").click(function (e) {
    $(e.target).addClass("selected");
});
```

Your code won't work anyways, as the click event is bound only to the `#treeview` element, and when that element fires, `e.target` will always be the `#treeview` element. What you're looking for is probably something like this:

```
$("#treeview li").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

This binds the click function to all `li` elements, and when one of them is clicked, it adds the "selected" class to that element.

Probably you want to also allow deselecting of objects, so you should use `toggleClass` instead of `addClass`. If you want to allow selecting of only one object, you could use this:

```
$("#treeview li").click(function() {
    // Clear all selected states
    $('#treeview li').removeClass('selected');
    // Set current as selected
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was in the middle of answering exactly this, but Tatu got it first.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#browser").treeview({
        toggle:function(){
            console.log($(this).find('ul li'));
        }
    });
```

Toggle is a callback for click. The 'this' value represents the 'li' that contains de 'ul' with the tree contents. In this case the console wills find all the 'li' nested inside 'ul'